# InfluxDB timestamps don't appear to use the provided timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp, influxdb, influxdb-python

I am sending data to an InfluxDB database using the [Python client library](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python). The example given uses the `time` method from the [`Point` class](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python/blob/master/influxdb_client/client/write/point.py), which is supposed to allow for writing data with a provided timestamp rather than the data received time at the server.

I am using the following imports:

```
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS
from influxdb_client.domain.write_precision import WritePrecision
```

And I have the following code segments for constructing the `Point` and sending it using the `write` method:

```
def get_shark_intervals(sharks, buffer):
  for shark in sharks:
    demand    = Shark.decode_readings(shark.read([Shark.DEMAND]))
    interval  = Shark.decode_datetime(shark.read([Shark.INTERVAL]))
    if demand is None or interval is None:
      return
    print(interval)
    buffer.append(
      [
        int(datetime(
          2000 + interval[0],
          interval[1],
          interval[2],
          interval[3],
          interval[4],
          interval[5]
        ).timestamp()),
        "L1",
        shark.get_equipment(),
        shark.get_description(),
        shark.get_nom_voltage(),
        "DEMAND",
        int(demand[0][1])
      ]
    )
    print(buffer[-1][0])
  return
```

```
def flush_buffer(influx, buffer):
  len_buffer = len(buffer)
  points = [0] * len_buffer

  for i in range(0, len_buffer):
    point = Point("consumption")                                  \
      .tag("location",        buffer[i][1])                       \
      .tag("equipment",       buffer[i][2])                       \
      .tag("description",     buffer[i][3])                       \
      .tag("nominal_voltage", buffer[i][4])                       \
      .tag("type",            buffer[i][5])                       \
      .field("W",             buffer[i][6])                       \
      .time(buffer[i][0],     write_precision = WritePrecision.S)

    points[i] = point

  influx.write(
    bucket          = BUCKET,
    record          = points,
    write_precision = WritePrecision.S
  )

  buffer = []
  
  return
```

For the two `print` statements in my code, I get this output:

[image: Output from print statements with datetime information]

The list is formatted as [Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second], and the Unix timestamp lines up with the items in the list when converted; however, as seen below, InfluxDB appears to be using the server received timestamp when displaying a query:

[image: Example graph of incorrect timestamp]

[image: Example graph of incorrect timestamp]

This is also seen in the raw data where `_time` doesn't match the provided timestamps:

[image: Raw data with incorrect time column]

Comment: When testing additional telemetry with a 1-second sampling interval and a 10-second upload interval, all the timestamps are synchronized to the 10-second intervals, so it appears InfluxDB is ignoring the timestamp in the Point being sent.